# having problems with the shopify php api when looking for the shopify_api

Tags: php, api, shopify

PHP API using: https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify_api

1. I have PHP 5.3.27 installed
2. I installed Composer (by going to
   the website and using their install.exe)

It mentions that

> "This will download shopify_api into the
>   vendor/sandeepshetty/shopify_api directory."

But I do not see the folders or files anywhere on the computer.

Comment: have you done a search on your computer for the folder `shopify_api`

Comment: Yes i did a complete search on the whole c drive

Answer (score 0):

The plugin author is saying that if you download Composer with the instructions he provided (via Terminal), then Composer will autoload those files for you. Unfortunately, though easier, simply going to the source URL for the Composer tool won't do that for you.

First, make sure you have created the composer.json file and stored it in your project directory. Then, log into your server or system via the command line (Terminal for Mac OS, Putty for Windows). Cd into your project directory, and install by entering these commands:

`$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar install`